# 403 when posting in postman using Yeoman's Angular-Fullstack

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I am trying to populate a local db using MongoDB in my Yeoman Angular-fullstack application.  I used the endpoint command:

```
yo angular-fullstack:endpoint [options] <name>
```

and can get to the route, but it is an empty object.  It will not allow me to post.

I am getting the error: 
 **Connect 403 Error: CSRF token missing**

Mongod is running fine.

There is authentication on the page, but at this point no forbidden routes.

Thank you for your hellp.

Answer (score 11):

Go to your .\server\config\express.js and either change xssProtection to false or add an 'development' !== env to the if statement:

```
if ('test' !== env && 'development' !== env) { // <- add development env here
    console.log("using lusca");

    app.use(lusca({
      csrf: {
        angular: true
      },
      xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
      hsts: {
        maxAge: 31536000, //1 year, in seconds
        includeSubDomains: true,
        preload: true
      },
      xssProtection: true // <- or change this to false
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

or comment these lines located in \server\config\express.js

```
 csrf: {
        angular: true
      },
```